# Firebase React Native project returns "auth/network-request-failed" on sign up screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, jsx

I'm creating the sign up screen for my chat app in react native and when I try to create an account I recieve `Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).` on console. The Firebase JS SDK version is ^10.4.0. Here's a part of SignUp.js that handles the login:

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../config';

//Ignore these two constants :)
const background = require('../assets/background.png');
const logo = require('../assets/logo.png');

export default class SignUp extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          email: "",
          password: ""
        };
    }

    handleLogin = (email, password) => {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
    };
```

Also the config.js where I'm initializing firebase:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

I've already tried using `firebase@8.2.3` but it returned errors with AsyncStorage(that I'm not using). Also tried using `@react-native-firebase` but it required a lot of files on the project. I'm having the same problem in Expo Go and in web.

EDIT: I solved the problem, just called email and password this way: `const { email, password } = this.state;` instead of calling (email, password) as parameters. Also, this is the new config.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});
```